# C# ErrorProvider CapsLock Pressed

Tags: c#, error-handling, capslock

I'm trying to write something that will notify the user with an Error Provider that the caps lock is on before inputting their username/password. I've found some code that works that looks like this:

```
private void nameInputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
        {
            pizzaErrorProvider.SetError(nameInputTextBox, "Must be lowercase only.");
        }

        else
        {
            pizzaErrorProvider.SetError(nameInputTextBox, null);
        }

    }
```

However, it only notifies the user once they start typing and I'm interesting if I can get it to appear as soon as the caps lock is pressed. I'm thinking maybe I have to write something that checks the state of the capslock key and then notifying once it's been pressed? Is that possible to do? Is this the right path to look down for this?

Comment: Probably better with a global keyboard hook, though there is other ways, what are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: you might be better off just checking on the textbox keydown if the caps lock is pressed...less complicated than the global key hook...you wont know immediately...but youll know when the key is pressed...and can cancel the event if the caps lock is pressed if you wanted

Comment: Why not just convert the given input to lowercase? I mean, the user can still `SHIFT`+ `any letter` with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can only know if capslock is active by capturing a keyboard event. as you are doing here.

as @Michael suggestes you can create a global keyboard hook and make a static IsCapslock property which you will set by the hook.

Either on setting this property or on opening your form you can already warn the user of capslock being used. If there is no keyboard even prior to start typing. the first letter might indeed be the first time you know if capslock is active.